# How to not allow connections to Node.js HTTP server or TCP stack while the event loop is blocking?

Tags: node.js, async-hooks

Given I would know that the Node.js event loop is blocking on a specific operation or through `async_hooks`, how could I tell Node and the TCP stack not to accept connections temporarily during that blocking time, so LoadBalancers will not try reach the server?

Comment: Nothing will happen if the loop is blocked, but you shouldn't block the loop in the first place. What use case do you have here?

Comment: There is a potential for timeouts or at least clients will have a pending connection. Unfortunately I don't have much of choice given how the Postgres client libraries work, or not work. E.g. the PG stream lib would help but has a bug.

Comment: The Postgres driver should be non-blocking, so unless you're making sync calls for some reason you should be fine. Which driver are you using here? If you're trying to prevent your HTTP servers from becoming overloaded you may need to tune your load balancer to backlog requests if they're servicing "too many", where you need to define too many somehow.

Comment: Unfortunately it is though. `node-postgres`. I think it's during serialisation of very large result sets. It's actually "fine" that is blocking, because I can mitigate this with architecture very easily and the cases are rare.

backpressuring the LB would be want to look for. I just don't now what low level metric a HAProxy could take. My thinking was to propagate this the "too busy" information through some kind of TCP mechanism, because that one will be able to act during the blocking duration.

Comment: It's not easy to get things to back-off like that. What you could do is have some kind of middleware layer like [RabbitMQ](http://rabbitmq.com) where you can properly regulate job flow and delegate those to workers, but honestly it sounds like you just need more Node processes to service your requests and avoid bottlenecking.

Comment: Yeah, both seems fine. More processes will only randomly help though, because the one with the blocking event loop is still reachable. I might start my efforts from the LB side, trying to find a good "passive" metric.

Comment: For ref: the APi I am servicing is running on Kubernetes with at least a couple of horizontally scaled similar containers. The API will always be available, but I want to avoid degraded performance.

Comment: You can also split out your Node HTTP process into a multi-process model using IPC and the [cluster mechanism](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html). That might allow you to send signals back to your load balancer that you've refused the request and it should retry another worker in the pool. You need to keep your HTTP responder in a state where it can always respond. As an experiment you could try [webworkers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads) for your serialization problem.